# Amazon S3 for static assets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I followed the tutorial from `asset_sync` gem.

It looks ok, but I still don't understand something.

1. I'll have to run `rake assets:precompile` every time I want to update the assets, right? But if I wan't to run it only local, without sync? If I have to run it locally, why I have to put a lot of environment variables in heroku relating to S3?
2. It looks to me, [looking at logs](https://gist.github.com/caarlos0/816b8942e94adbecca73), that rails somehow get the sass files instead of compiled CSS files (and also throw some error because of that). How can I fix that?

[github link](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)

Comment: do you mean the `asset_sync` gem?

Comment: yes, sorry. I'll fix the question.

Comment: Link to logs is broken

Comment: Where does it say that you have to EVER run `rake assets:precompile`? No such thing in docs.